# My ubuntu 13.04 keeps freezing

Tags: intel, 32-bit

I have just installed Ubuntu 13.04 on my PC dual-booting it with Windows 7, then reboots but when I start to use Ubuntu for about 20 mins it freezes every thing but the mouse. The keyboard doesn't work and I cant use the mouse to click everything, then crashes nothing loads

My PC specs are

---

- SPECS
- RAM: 2gb
- Processor: 1.6 Intel atom 32bit operating system

Comment: Can you add either your graphics card model or the make and model of computer?

Comment: Have you tried unity-2d? Is it freezing?

Comment: How can this be closed as "end of life". On May 5th 2013 this was clearly NOT end of life. Abbandoned question, ok but eol? No :)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have faulty RAM on your video card.

Ubuntu's 3D window manager probably uses more RAM than the one in Windows, so in Windows you never use enough video RAM to have a need to access the part of RAM that is bad, but in Ubuntu where you use more video memory the bad memory is accessed.

When a video card crashes it causes the symptoms you reported.

Go to the store and buy another video card and try it. If it doesn't fix the problem take the video card back to the store. If it does fix the problem, keep the video card and the fix to your problem.